# Is there a way to merge @Configurations that extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter into one @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'd like to merge two configurations into one configuration.  Here's how they currently look:

## WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(...)
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
     //...
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        //...
    }
```

## WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"..."})
@Import({
        ...
})
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("..."),
        @PropertySource(
                ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                value = "...")
})
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AdminConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //...
    }
```

I've looked through the Spring class hierarchy and seen that these do not extend classes that are related in any way.  Are there annotations that exist to replace them?  Can this be solved by implementing interfaces instead of extending classes?

The reason I want to merge these is because I want to have a single config so that I don't have to think about which one to use when I'm testing my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t suggest placing them in the same class. This is not advisable for the same reason you don't cram all of your logic in a single class. Keep your configuration concise and to the point. What's more is this can really get nasty w/ circular bean references at times.

I'd recommend doing composition to solve your problem:

```java
@Configuration
@Import({AdminConfig.class, WebApplicationConfig.class})
public class TheConfig {}
```

Now you can just refer to `TheConfig`.

Alternatively, if this only about tests you can place the configurations on a [meta annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-annotations-meta) For example:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {..})
public @interface TheTests { }
```

Finally if you really want to use a single class you can do something like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(...)
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"..."})
@Import({
        ...
})
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("..."),
        @PropertySource(
                ignoreResourceNotFound = true,
                value = "...")
})
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class TheConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
}
```

The additional problem with this is that `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is provided so you don't need to implement all the methods in the API (only the ones you need). What's more is it shields you from changes within the interface which may add methods.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most idiomatic approach is to make each configurer a static nested class on the top-level `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Import the top-level class, and Spring will import the nested configurations as well.